Converting Legacy Controls to Content Controls [In Word] using VBA sometimes doesn't work
Because of an issue that the old forms are causing in my company, I need to switch all our letters over to using the new content controls.  There are ~120 letters with an average of 20 controls on every form, so it would be a lot of work to do manually. I did a search and found this to do it automatically: Convert Legacy Controls to Content Controls
I have taken that code and modified it some by cleaning it up and adding some more functionality:
    Sub ConvertLegacyControlsToContentControls()
    
        Dim FF As FormField
        Dim CC As ContentControl
        Dim DefaultText, FieldName As String
        Dim NumOfFields As Long, ComboEntryNum, FieldFontSize, FieldType As Long
        Dim CheckValue As Boolean
        Dim ComboBoxValuess() As String
        Dim FieldRng As Range
        Dim doc As Document: Set doc = ActiveDocument
        
        For NumOfFields = doc.FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set FF = doc.FormFields(NumOfFields)
            Set FieldRng = FF.Range
            FieldFontSize = FieldRng.Font.Size
            FieldType = FF.Type
            If FieldType = 83 Or FieldType = 70 Then
                DefaultText = FF.Result
                FieldName = FF.Name
            End If
            Select Case FieldType
                Case 83 'Comboboxes
                    ReDim ComboBoxValuess(1 To FF.DropDown.ListEntries.Count)
                    For ComboEntryNum = 1 To FF.DropDown.ListEntries.Count
                        ComboBoxValuess(ComboEntryNum) = FF.DropDown.ListEntries(ComboEntryNum).Name
                    Next ComboEntryNum
                    FF.Delete
                    Set CC = doc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList, FieldRng)
                    CC.DropdownListEntries.Add CC.PlaceholderText, vbNullString
                    For ComboEntryNum = 1 To UBound(ComboBoxValuess)
                        CC.DropdownListEntries.Add ComboBoxValuess(ComboEntryNum), ComboBoxValuess(ComboEntryNum)
                        If CC.DropdownListEntries(CC.DropdownListEntries.Count).Value = DefaultText Then
                            CC.DropdownListEntries(CC.DropdownListEntries.Count).Select
                        End If
                    Next ComboEntryNum
                Case 71 ' Check Boxes
                    CheckValue = FF.CheckBox.Value
                    FF.Delete
                    Set CC = doc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlCheckBox, FieldRng)
                    CC.Checked = CheckValue
                Case 70 'Text Fields
                    FF.Delete
                    FieldRng.End = 560
                    FieldRng.Select
                    Set CC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            End Select
            If FieldType = 83 Or FieldType = 70 Then
                With CC
                    .Range.Text = DefaultText
                    .Range.Font.Size = FieldFontSize
                    .Title = FieldName
                End With
            End If
        Next NumOfFields
     
    End Sub

The code works 60% of the time.  The 40% of the time it doesn't work, I get a Object doesn't support this action (Error 445).  They are the same type of controls also?  I do not see a difference.  I have been trying to see if there was a property that was different but I cannot see anything that is different.  I will say that currently it is only happening on Text Fields.  I have tried to add both wdContentControlText and wdContentControlRichText.  Has anyone experienced this issue?  have any ideas?  I have looked and cannot find anyone else having this issue.
The
    FieldRng.End = 560
    FieldRng.Select

in the code was me trying to select the range or modify its size.  I don't think it is necessary. Also Set CC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText) was originally Set CC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText, Fieldrng).  I was just testing without the Fieldrng also.

EDIT:

I figured out why it is happening.  I converted all these files from old .dot to .dotx files but I did it through code:
Call wDoc.SaveAs2(FileName:=strFilePath & "\" & strFileName & ".dotx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplate)

It seems that while it is saving the file with the .dotx extension, it is still saving the file as the legacy .dot file type.  If I open the file, save it manually as a .dotx or a docx it works without an issue.  Now, I want to figure out if I can somehow fix this through code or do I have to manually resave all these files.

Which exact line(s) are giving the error?

When you get the Object doesn't support this action message and click on the Debug button, is a line in your code highlighted? Which one?

Take a look at Greg Maxey's Add-In.  http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html

Hi @JohnKorchok I converted to the code below that macropod suggested but I have the same issue.  It is happening on the same line equivalent, which is this: Set CCtrl = .ContentControls.Add(Type:=wdContentControlText, Range:=FldRng)

Try the following - it's a bit more sophisticated.
Sub ConvertLegacyControlsToContentControls()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FmFld As FormField, CCtrl As ContentControl, FldRng As Range
Dim StrDef As String, StrRslt As String, FldNm As String, StrFntNm As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, SngFntSz As Single, FldFmt As Long, StrFmt As String
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set FmFld = .FormFields(i)
    With FmFld
      StrDef = .TextInput.Default
      StrFmt = .TextInput.Format
      StrRslt = .Result
      FldNm = .Name
      FldFmt = .TextInput.Type
      SngFntSz = .Range.Font.Size
      StrFntNm = .Range.Font.Name
      Set FldRng = .Range: FldRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    End With
    Set CCtrl = .ContentControls.Add(Type:=wdContentControlText, Range:=FldRng)
    With CCtrl
      .Title = FldNm
      If StrDef <> StrRslt Then .Range.Text = StrRslt
      .Range.Font.Size = SngFntSz
      .Range.Font.Name = StrFntNm
    End With
    Select Case FmFld.Type
      Case wdFieldFormTextInput
          If StrDef <> "" Then CCtrl.SetPlaceholderText Text:=StrDef
          If FldFmt = 2 Then
            If StrDef = StrRslt Then CCtrl.Range.Text = ""
            CCtrl.Type = wdContentControlDate
            CCtrl.DateDisplayFormat = StrFmt
          End If
      Case wdFieldFormDropDown
        With CCtrl
          .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
          For j = 1 To FmFld.DropDown.ListEntries.Count
            .DropdownListEntries.Add Text:=FmFld.DropDown.ListEntries(j).Name
          Next
          .SetPlaceholderText Text:=.DropdownListEntries(1)
          .Type = wdContentControlText
          .Range.Text = ""
          .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
        End With
      Case wdFieldFormCheckBox
        CCtrl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox
        CCtrl.Checked = FmFld.CheckBox.Value
    End Select
    FmFld.Delete
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


hi Macropod.  I converted my code to use yours but I am having the same issue. I even tried the add-in that Charles suggested above.  That also has the same issue.  I am going to upload a test file that has the issue.

Well, unless you can at least tell us what kind of field it's failing on or, better still, provide a link to an actual document we can work with, we'd only be guessing.

I said in the post edit how to replicate the issue

You also said you were going to upload a test file. In any event, I suspect your file-format problem is because you're simply adding the .dotx extension to it - after the .dot extension that's already there.

Sorry I was going to until I figured out the issue.  I am not just putting the x on the end, I supplied the code that I use to create the new version but it seems not to convert it.

As I said, the file save code you posted indicates you're adding '.dotx' to the extension after the existing '.dot' extension. In reality, all you need to add is the 'x'.
